# Select with TypoScript with condition

Tags: select, typo3, typoscript

I got this condition:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_car = Katowice]
  get_carpid = TEXT
  get_carpid.value = 27  
[global]
```

And this select:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.formhandler-multistep-forms.markers.input_readonly_a_price = CONTENT
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.formhandler-multistep-forms.markers.input_readonly_a_price {
            table = tx_pricelist_prices_full
            select {
              pidInList = 27
              orderBy = uid
              selectFields = uid, group_a_1_3
              # possible conditions
               where = ( tx_pricelist_prices_full.uid='1' AND hidden='0' AND deleted='0')
            } 
            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
              #value  
              1 = TEXT
              1.insertData = 1 
              1.data = field:group_a_1_3
              2 = TEXT
              2.value = *
              3 = TEXT
              3.insertData = 1 
              3.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day          
              stdWrap.prioriCalc = 1   
            }
}
```

How to use defined get_carpid in SELECT in line pidInList = get_carpid

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cObject CASE. But this will only work for [a-zA-z0-9_-]

```
# TS Setup
... snip  ...
pidInList.cObject = CASE
pidInList.cObject {
  key.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_car
  key.case = lower
  default = TEXT
  default.value = 0

  # special chars are not allowed
  katowice = TEXT
  katowice.value = 27 
}
... snip  ...
```

A different possibility is to use constants:

```
# TS Constants
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_car = Katowice]
  get_carpid = 27  
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|get_car = Lublin]
  get_carpid = 28  
[global]

# TS Setup
... snip  ...
pidInList = {$get_carpid}
... snip  ...
```

The first solution is more TypoScript fun, the second easier for novice - i guess :)